# Bottom navigation and icon size

Tags: android

I am using bottom navigation view where the icons are SVG.
For some reason, I noticed that the icons in the navigation bar are a little bit squeezed horizontally and longer vertically.

What should be the icon size? Shouldn't SVG be suitable for any size?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Vector drawables used for BottomNavigationView icons should have the same width and height. It doesn't matter what the intrinsic width and height are, as long as they're the same.

---

Vector drawables can scale to any size without becoming pixellated, but that doesn't mean that you can change the aspect ratio without distorting the original image.

Android vector drawables specify an "intrinsic size", which is how large they will be if you don't specify an explicit size:

```
android:width="48dp"
android:height="48dp"
```

and a "viewport size", which defines the coordinate space for the vector paths:

```
android:viewportWidth="24.0"
android:viewportHeight="24.0"
```

If your vector drawable had an original intrinsic size of 24dp x 24dp, but you display it at 48dp x 36dp, you will see that it is "stretched" horizontally.